# Determine Isosceles Right Triangle in C++

Tags: c++

## As you know

**Isosceles Right Triangle** are have *right triangle* and *Isosceles triangle* feature.

Example:

```
int a,b,c; //a,b and c are three triangle edge.
cout << "please insert a,b,c" << endl;
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cin >> c;
if(a==b || b==c || c==a){
   cout << "isosceles triangle";
}
else if(a*a==b*b+c*c ||b*b==c*c+a*a || c*c==a*a+b*b)
{
   cout<<"right triangle");
}
```

This is how i determine right triangle and isosceles triangle

Why i dont just do like this

```
if(pow(a,2)==pow(b,2)+pow(c,2) ||pow(b,2)==pow(c,2)+pow(a,2) || pow(c,2)==pow(a,2)+pow(b,2)){
        if(a==b || b==c || c==a){
            cout << "isosceles right triangle";
        }
        else{
            cout << "right tri";
        }
 }
```

The problem is: Determine **Isosceles Right Triangle** must input square root number.

[Isosceles Right Triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IsoscelesRightTriangle.html)

Question: when a=1,b=1,c=sqrt(2)

How to determine it as a Isosceles Right Triangle in C++

Comment: "Determine Isosceles Right Triangle must input square root number.". What does this sentence mean? I don't understand what you want to achieve here.

Comment: You can store those "features" in bools, like `bool isRight=a*a==b*b+c*c ||b*b==c*c+a*a || c*c==a*a+b*b;` and then print output based on their values.

Comment: BTW, the `pow` function takes *floating point* parameters.  You may want to use multiplication instead such as `a * a`.  You may loose accuracy due to conversion between floating point and integer.

Comment: @geza means that side of Isosceles Right Triangle minimum will be 1,1,squre root of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Evg's comment, here's an example implementation:

```
bool IsRightTriangle(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double max_allowed_error = 0.1;
    return (std::abs(a*a - b*b - c*c) <= max_allowed_error) || (std::abs(b*b - c*c - a*a) <= max_allowed_error) || (std::abs(c*c - a*a - b*b) <= max_allowed_error) ;
}

bool IsIsosceles(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return a == b || b == c || c == a;
}

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    cout << "\nEnter length of first side of the triangle ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nEnter length of second side of the triangle ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "\nEnter length of third side of the triangle ";
    cin >> c;    

    bool iso = IsIsosceles(a, b, c);
    bool rt = IsRightTriangle(a, b, c);

    if (iso && rt) std::cout << "\n Triangle is a Right Isosceles Triangle\n";
    else
        if (iso) std::cout << "\n Triangle is an Isosceles Triangle \n";
        else
            if (rt) std::cout << "\n Triangle is a Right Triangle \n";
}
```

Comment: In `IsRightTriangle` I suggest returning `(std::abs(...) <= ...) || (std::abs(...) <= ...) || (std::abs(...) <= ...)`. In `IsIsosceles` you also need `max_allowed_error`.

Comment: @Evg: Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your example all side lengths, `a`, `b` and `c`, have type `int`. No isosceles right triangle can have all integral side lengths. Probably, you should use `float` or `double`.

If you know how to do the test mathematically, it should be pretty simple to implement it in code. The only thing to bear in mind is that direct comparison of floating point numbers is meaningless in most cases because of rounding errors.

Mathematical equality a<sup>2</sup> = b<sup>2</sup> + c<sup>2</sup> should be checked like this:

```
std::abs(a*a - b*b - c*c) < EPSILON
```

where `EPSILON` is some small number to tolerate finite precision of floating point numbers.